# How to apply CSS in jQuery Datatables plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I would like to apply CSS to a checkbox in the [jQuery Datatables plugin](http://datatables.net/). Now this CSS value would change under certain conditions , which is if true then I want to display the checkbox is red color else white.

I tried using the sClass attribute , but it gets applied to all the boxes. How can I apply them to the checkboxes depending upon the condition individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a css style for custumized checkbox

```
 .lala{color:red;}
```

now you can add this class to your desired CB with jQuery addClass() like:

```
$(this).addClass("lala")
```

Answer (score 1):

Have the boxes carry classes names that refer to your conditions.

```
<checkbox class="condition1" ..... </...>
```

And then use the classnames `condition_etc` to style the boxes accordingly.